# Set-theoretic difference between cartesian products as a disjoint union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $m$ be any positive natural number and let $A_1$, $C_1$, ..., $A_m$, $C_m$ be arbitrary sets. Is this correct?

$(A_1 \times A_2 \times A_3 \times A_4 \times ... \times A_{m-1} \times A_m) \setminus (C_1 \times C_2 \times C_3 \times C_4 \times ... \times C_{m-1} \times C_m) =$

$= [(A_1 \setminus C_1) \times A_2 \times A_3 \times A_4 \times ... \times A_{m-1} \times A_m] \dot{\cup} $

$ \dot{\cup} [C_1 \times (A_2 \setminus C_2) \times A_3 \times A_4 \times ... \times A_{m-1} \times A_m] \dot{\cup}$

$\dot{\cup} [C_1 \times C_2 \times (A_3 \setminus C_3) \times A_4 \times ... \times A_{m-1} \times A_m] \dot{\cup} ... $

$ ... \dot{\cup} [C_1 \times C_2 \times C_3 \times C_4 \times ... \times C_{m-1} \times (A_m \setminus C_m)]$.

How to prove it?

Thanks

Comment: if a point does not belong to LHS then there is a first index $k$ such that the $k$-th coordinate of the point does not belong to $C_k$, this observation relates to RHS. LHS and RHS are standard abbreviations in math for Left Hand Side and Right Hand Side of an equation.

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand. What is a "LHS" and a "RHS"?

Comment: You mean that "if a point DOES belong to LHS then there is a first index $k$ such that the $k$-th coordinate of the point does not belong to $C_k$, this observation relates to RHS". Ok I got that! Thanks.

Comment: yes, you are right, if  point DOES belong to LHS etc